# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() - Numpy Library

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have seen this same topic some other place but no real answer to my question. I have a numpy array and I need to find the index of a number.

```
a=np.argsort(cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[11:12], tfidf_matrix)) #numbers are from 0 to 11

b=np.equal(a,10)

# b values are [[False False False False False False False False  True False False False]]
```

How do I get it to return index 8? (The index for the true value in the array)

Comment: The solution is in the error message which you put as the title of your question. Do you want to test if *any* of the elements equal 10, or do you want to test if they *all* equal 10?

Comment: `indices = np.where(a == 10)[0]` will give you an array of indices where `a` equals 10. Just google `numpy.where` and read the docs.

Comment: What expression produced the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```py
b = np.where(a==10)
```

Here `b` will be an array that contains the indices of the items that matched your condition. You can select the first element (`b[0]`) if you are interested only in the first occurrence of the item.

The documentation on [numpy.equal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html) says that:

> Return (x1 == x2) element-wise.

And that is exactly what you received, an array that contains an element wise comparison of the array `a` and the value `10`.